# Running the same purrr command on two different machines (windows 10 desktop) and (AWS Linux server) giving an error

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, purrr

I have running on my desktop (windows 10) R studio and the code I am running works fine without error. However I would like to perform the following code on an Amazon AWS server (Ubuntu).

The server is the following AMI ID `RStudio-1.1.456_R-3.5.1_CUDA-9.0_cuDNN-7.2.1_ubuntu-16.04-LTS-64bit (ami-01d45add662773bed)` from `www.louisaslett.com`.

The error I am running into on the AWS server is `Error: Argument 1 is a list, must contain atomic vectors`.

I have madesure `plyr` is not loaded before `dplyr`. Does anyone run into the same issue on their linux machines?

The code I am trying to run is;

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
data_details2 <- map_df(data_details, pluck, 'information', .id  = 'id') %>% 
  full_join(map_df(data_details, pluck, 'filings', .id = 'id'), by = 'id')
```

SessionInfo() on Windows 10 R studio:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] data.table_1.12.0 xlsx_0.6.1        lubridate_1.7.4   forcats_0.3.0     stringr_1.3.1    
 [6] purrr_0.2.5       readr_1.3.1       tidyr_0.8.2       tibble_2.0.1      ggplot2_3.0.0    
[11] tidyverse_1.2.1   rvest_0.3.2       xml2_1.2.0        edgarWebR_1.0.0   dplyr_0.8.0.1    
[16] rugarch_1.4-0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] mclust_5.4.2                Rcpp_1.0.0                  mvtnorm_1.0-8              
 [4] lattice_0.20-38             xlsxjars_0.6.1              zoo_1.8-4                  
 [7] assertthat_0.2.0            truncnorm_1.0-8             R6_2.4.0                   
[10] cellranger_1.1.0            plyr_1.8.4                  backports_1.1.3            
[13] httr_1.4.0                  pillar_1.3.1                rlang_0.3.1                
[16] curl_3.3                    lazyeval_0.2.1              readxl_1.2.0               
[19] rstudioapi_0.9.0            nloptr_1.2.1                SkewHyperbolic_0.4-0       
[22] Matrix_1.2-15               munsell_0.5.0               broom_0.5.1                
[25] compiler_3.5.3              numDeriv_2016.8-1           modelr_0.1.2               
[28] pkgconfig_2.0.2             DistributionUtils_0.6-0     Rsolnp_1.16                
[31] tidyselect_0.2.5            expm_0.999-3                crayon_1.3.4               
[34] withr_2.1.2                 GeneralizedHyperbolic_0.8-4 MASS_7.3-51.1              
[37] grid_3.5.3                  nlme_3.1-137                jsonlite_1.6               
[40] gtable_0.2.0                magrittr_1.5                scales_1.0.0               
[43] KernSmooth_2.23-15          cli_1.0.1                   stringi_1.2.4              
[46] xts_0.11-2                  generics_0.0.2              spd_2.0-1                  
[49] tools_3.5.3                 glue_1.3.0                  hms_0.4.2                  
[52] ks_1.11.3                   yaml_2.2.0                  colorspace_1.4-0           
[55] rJava_0.9-10                haven_2.0.0
```

The sessioninfo() for the Ubuntu AWS is the following;

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] usethis_1.5.0     devtools_2.0.2    data.table_1.12.2 lubridate_1.7.4  
 [5] forcats_0.3.0     stringr_1.3.1     readr_1.1.1       tidyr_0.8.1      
 [9] tibble_2.1.1      ggplot2_3.0.0     tidyverse_1.2.1   dplyr_0.8.0.1    
[13] rvest_0.3.3       xml2_1.2.0        edgarWebR_1.0.0   purrr_0.2.5      
[17] rdrop2_0.8.1      RStudioAMI_0.3.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.5  remotes_2.0.4     haven_1.1.2       lattice_0.20-35  
 [5] colorspace_1.3-2  yaml_2.2.0        base64enc_0.1-3   rlang_0.3.4      
 [9] pkgbuild_1.0.3    pillar_1.3.1      glue_1.3.0        withr_2.1.2      
[13] sessioninfo_1.1.1 modelr_0.1.2      readxl_1.1.0      plyr_1.8.4       
[17] munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.2.0      cellranger_1.1.0  memoise_1.1.0    
[21] callr_3.0.0       ps_1.1.0          curl_3.2          broom_0.5.0      
[25] Rcpp_1.0.1        scales_1.0.0      backports_1.1.2   desc_1.2.0       
[29] pkgload_1.0.2     jsonlite_1.5      fs_1.2.6          hms_0.4.2        
[33] digest_0.6.17     stringi_1.2.4     processx_3.2.0    rprojroot_1.3-2  
[37] grid_3.5.1        cli_1.1.0         tools_3.5.1       magrittr_1.5     
[41] lazyeval_0.2.1    crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.2   prettyunits_1.0.2
[45] assertthat_0.2.0  httr_1.3.1        rstudioapi_0.7    R6_2.2.2         
[49] nlme_3.1-137      compiler_3.5.1
```

Data:

```
    data_details <- list(`0000066740` = list(information = structure(list(name = "3M CO", 
    cik = "0000066740", fiscal_year_end = "1231", company_href = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000066740&owner=exclude&count=100", 
    sic = "3841", sic_description = "SURGICAL &amp; MEDICAL INSTRUMENTS &amp; APPARATUS", 
    state_location = "MN", state_incorporation = "DE", mailing_city = "ST. PAUL", 
    mailing_state = "MN", mailing_zip = "55144-1000", mailing_street = "3M CENTER", 
    mailing_street2 = "BLDG. 220-11W-02", business_city = "ST PAUL", 
    business_state = "MN", business_zip = "55144-1000", business_street = "3M CENTER", 
    business_street2 = "BLDG. 220-11W-02", business_phone = "6517332204"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), filings = structure(list(accession_number = c("0001558370-19-000470", 
"0001558370-18-000535", "0001558370-17-000479", "0001558370-16-003162", 
"0001104659-15-009560", "0001104659-14-009773", "0001104659-13-010881", 
"0001104659-12-010566", "0001104659-11-007845", "0001104659-10-007295", 
"0001104659-09-009669", "0001104659-08-011226", "0001104659-07-013613", 
"0001104659-06-010894", "0001104659-05-008057", "0000897101-04-000425", 
"0000066740-03-000005", "0000066740-02-000006", "0000066740-01-000003", 
"0000066740-00-000005", "0000066740-99-000002", "0000066740-98-000004", 
"0000066740-98-000002", "0000066740-97-000003", "0000066740-96-000005", 
"0000066740-95-000003", "0000066740-94-000014", "0000066740-94-000010", 
"0000066740-94-000013", "0000066740-94-000007"), act = c("34", 
"34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", 
"34", "34", "34", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), file_number = c("001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", 
"001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", 
"001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", 
"001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", 
"001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", 
"001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", "001-03285", 
"001-03285", "001-03285"), filing_date = structure(c(1549494000, 
1518044400, 1486594800, 1455145200, 1423695600, 1392246000, 1360796400, 
1329346800, 1297810800, 1266274800, 1234825200, 1203030000, 1172444400, 
1140476400, 1109199600, 1078182000, 1047250800, 1015801200, 982623600, 
950828400, 918774000, 890953200, 889484400, 858034800, 826498800, 
794444400, 763340400, 763340400, 762994800, 762994800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), accepted_date = structure(c(1549494000, 
1518044400, 1486594800, 1455145200, 1423695600, 1392246000, 1360796400, 
1329346800, 1297810800, 1266274800, 1234479600, 1203030000, 1172185200, 
1140476400, 1109199600, 1078182000, 1047250800, 1015801200, 982623600, 
950828400, 918774000, 890953200, 889484400, 858034800, 826498800, 
794444400, 763340400, 763340400, 762994800, 762994800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), href = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000155837019000470/0001558370-19-000470-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000155837018000535/0001558370-18-000535-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000155837017000479/0001558370-17-000479-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000155837016003162/0001558370-16-003162-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465915009560/0001104659-15-009560-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465914009773/0001104659-14-009773-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465913010881/0001104659-13-010881-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465912010566/0001104659-12-010566-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465911007845/0001104659-11-007845-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465910007295/0001104659-10-007295-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465909009669/0001104659-09-009669-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465908011226/0001104659-08-011226-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465907013613/0001104659-07-013613-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465906010894/0001104659-06-010894-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000110465905008057/0001104659-05-008057-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000089710104000425/0000897101-04-000425-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000006674003000005/0000066740-03-000005-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000006674002000006/0000066740-02-000006-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000006674001000003/0000066740-01-000003-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-00-000005-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-99-000002-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-98-000004-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-98-000002-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-97-000003-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-96-000005-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-95-000003-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-94-000014-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-94-000010-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-94-000013-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/0000066740-94-000007-index.html"
), type = c("10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
"10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
"10-K", "10-K", "10-K405", "10-K405", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K/A", 
"10-K", "10-K", "10-K405", "10-K405", "10-K/A", "10-K/A", "10-K", 
"10-K"), film_number = c("19576031", "18586635", "17588296", 
"161412746", "15607397", "14606304", "13614520", "12619305", 
"11618481", "10606816", "09606477", "08623789", "07647410", "06633952", 
"05635854", "04643680", "03598517", "02571863", "1549874", "549348", 
"99536236", "98575319", "98561507", "97554254", "96533523", "95518801", 
"94517244", "00000000", "94517258", "00000000"), form_name = c("Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Sections 13 and 15(d), S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]"), description = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    size = c("43 MB", "42 MB", "41 MB", "40 MB", "37 MB", "36 MB", 
    "35 MB", "43 MB", "53 MB", "12 MB", "4 MB", "4 MB", "4 MB", 
    "3 MB", "3 MB", "973 KB", "376 KB", "256 KB", "261 KB", "189 KB", 
    "175 KB", "18 KB", "160 KB", "139 KB", "146 KB", "122 KB", 
    "66 KB", "67 KB", "138 KB", "138 KB")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")), `0000796343` = list(information = structure(list(
    name = "ADOBE INC.", cik = "0000796343", fiscal_year_end = "1130", 
    company_href = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000796343&owner=exclude&count=100", 
    sic = "7372", sic_description = "SERVICES-PREPACKAGED SOFTWARE", 
    state_location = "CA", state_incorporation = "DE", mailing_city = "SAN JOSE", 
    mailing_state = "CA", mailing_zip = "95110-2704", mailing_street = "345 PARK AVENUE", 
    mailing_street2 = NA_character_, business_city = "SAN JOSE", 
    business_state = "CA", business_zip = "95110-2704", business_street = "345 PARK AVE", 
    business_street2 = NA_character_, business_phone = "4085366000"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), filings = structure(list(accession_number = c("0000796343-19-000019", 
"0000796343-18-000015", "0000796343-17-000031", "0000796343-16-000224", 
"0000796343-15-000022", "0000796343-14-000004", "0000796343-13-000008", 
"0000796343-12-000003", "0000796343-11-000003", "0000796343-10-000003", 
"0000796343-09-000007", "0001047469-08-000497", "0001104659-07-007412", 
"0001104659-07-007286", "0001047469-06-001601", "0001047469-05-002143", 
"0001047469-04-003345", "0001104659-03-005245", "0001174947-03-000004", 
"0000912057-02-007164", "0000912057-01-006700", "0000912057-00-007295", 
"0001047469-99-006452", "0001047469-98-006671", "0000912057-97-006476", 
"0000912057-96-002896", "0000912057-95-004982", "0000912057-95-000843"
), act = c("34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", 
"34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), file_number = c("000-15175", "000-15175", 
"000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", 
"000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", 
"000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", 
"000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", 
"000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "000-15175", "001-07033", 
"000-15175"), filing_date = structure(c(1548370800, 1516575600, 
1484866800, 1453158000, 1421708400, 1390258800, 1358809200, 1327532400, 
1296082800, 1264114800, 1232665200, 1201129200, 1170716400, 1170630000, 
1139353200, 1107298800, 1075935600, 1048806000, 1046214000, 1014246000, 
983142000, 950655600, 919206000, 887670000, 856479600, 824943600, 
804376800, 792975600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    accepted_date = structure(c(1548370800, 1516575600, 1484866800, 
    1453158000, 1421708400, 1390258800, 1358809200, 1327532400, 
    1296082800, 1264114800, 1232665200, 1201129200, 1170716400, 
    1170630000, 1139353200, 1107298800, 1075935600, 1048806000, 
    1046214000, 1014246000, 983142000, 950655600, 919206000, 
    887670000, 856479600, 824943600, 804376800, 792975600), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), href = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634319000019/0000796343-19-000019-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634318000015/0000796343-18-000015-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634317000031/0000796343-17-000031-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634316000224/0000796343-16-000224-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634315000022/0000796343-15-000022-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634314000004/0000796343-14-000004-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634313000008/0000796343-13-000008-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634312000003/0000796343-12-000003-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634311000003/0000796343-11-000003-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634310000003/0000796343-10-000003-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634309000007/0000796343-09-000007-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000104746908000497/0001047469-08-000497-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000110465907007412/0001104659-07-007412-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000110465907007286/0001104659-07-007286-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000104746906001601/0001047469-06-001601-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000104746905002143/0001047469-05-002143-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000104746904003345/0001047469-04-003345-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000110465903005245/0001104659-03-005245-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000117494703000004/0001174947-03-000004-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000091205702007164/0000912057-02-007164-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000091205701006700/0000912057-01-006700-index.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000912057-00-007295-index.html", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0001047469-99-006452-index.html", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0001047469-98-006671-index.html", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000912057-97-006476-index.html", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000912057-96-002896-index.html", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000912057-95-004982-index.html", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000912057-95-000843-index.html"
    ), type = c("10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
    "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K/A", 
    "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K/A", "10-K", "10-K", 
    "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K/A", 
    "10-K"), film_number = c("19541150", "18539956", "17538661", 
    "161347007", "15533942", "14538201", "13541114", "12547794", 
    "11551468", "10540859", "09541987", "08546539", "07582649", 
    "07581400", "06589439", "05568498", "04570680", "03624074", 
    "03581551", "02555516", "1554608", "547290", "99544779", 
    "98543521", "97541318", "96524043", "95550446", "95513672"
    ), form_name = c("Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
    "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]"), 
    description = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), size = c("25 MB", "21 MB", "17 MB", "18 MB", 
    "30 MB", "28 MB", "25 MB", "32 MB", "23 MB", "14 MB", "5 MB", 
    "3 MB", "6 MB", "6 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", "236 KB", 
    "3 MB", "3 MB", "1 MB", "1 MB", "290 KB", "552 KB", "228 KB", 
    "349 KB", "61 KB", "437 KB")), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")))
```

Comment: The `R` version is also different

Comment: I am trying to update the AWS to the same version as the windows 10 version. Will report on the results